# PasteSpecial Column Widths

Tags: excel, vba, attributes, paste

Can anyone tell me why this is not pasting what is copied in the indicated cell

```
Dim FinalRow As String
        FinalRow1 = 112 - Quantity
        Let FinalRow = "112" & ":" & FinalRow1

        'Unhide Rows
        For i = 1 To Quantity
        Rows(FinalRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Next

        Dim RowToPaste As String
        RowToPaste = "C" & FinalRow1
        Range("C112:AM113").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range(RowToPaste).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        Range("C112:AM113").Select
        Selection.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        Range("C112:AM113").ClearContents
```

It does clears the contents and delete the borders, and I know it's copying cells "C112:AM113" but it is not pasting anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `xlPasteColumnWidths` it will only paste the column widths (without values). If you want to paste values use `xlPasteValues` or `xlPasteFormulas`